# How do I construct a Neo4j Cypher query that looks for nodes that have only links to a restricted list of nodes?

Tags: filter, neo4j, cypher, match

I need to construct a Cypher query that looks for nodes that have a specific subset of links to other nodes.  I.e., it excludes nodes that have any links to nodes outside a prescribed list. E.g., consider the following nodes/edges:

```
(a)->(d)
(a)->(e)
(a)->(f)

(b)->(d)    
(b)->(e)

(c)->(d)
```

How do I make a query that, for example, returns any node that has a link to (d) and/or (e) but nothing else?  I.e., (a) would be excluded from the result because it also links to (f), but the (b) and (c) would be included in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the list of neighbours of the candidate nodes to the list of nodes in the subset. For your case, all neighbours should be in the subset. (f) is not

```
WITH [d,e] AS subset
MATCH (n)
WHERE ALL(neighbour IN [(n)-->(m) | m] WHERE neighbour IN subset)
RETURN n
```

Comment: Thanks!  This helped tremendously.

Comment: @richardjones yw. Please accept the answer if it was what you were looking for.

Comment: Bit of a newbie.  Thanks!